# Why does matplotlib ax.transData.transform gives different values in different ipython cells? How to fix this?

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, transform, subplot, axes

I was suffering a really bizarre issue with matplotlib's `ax.transData.transform` in ipython. Basically, in the cell where `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` is declared, running `ax.transData.transform` for either the `x` or `y` axis is incorrect. However, if you run `ax.transData.transform` in a later cell, it returns the correct values.

To demonstrate, here is code running the transformation in the cell where `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` is declared:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_ylim(-2,2)
ax.set_xlim(-5,5)
nsize=[x*100 for x in d]
yradius = (ax.transData.transform([(0,2)]) - ax.transData.transform([(0,1)]))[0,1]
print("yRadius: {}".format(yradius))
xradius = (ax.transData.transform([(2,0)]) - ax.transData.transform([(1,0)]))[0,0]
print("xRadius: {}".format(xradius))
```

The print output is

```
yRadius: 54.360000000000014
xRadius: 33.48000000000002
```

In a cell below the above cell, if I run

```
yradius = (ax.transData.transform([(0,2)]) - ax.transData.transform([(0,1)]))[0,1]
print("yRadius: {}".format(yradius))
xradius = (ax.transData.transform([(2,0)]) - ax.transData.transform([(1,0)]))[0,0]
print("xRadius: {}".format(xradius))
```

The output is

```
yRadius: 33.48000000000002
xRadius: 33.48000000000002
```

Why are the values of the two cells not the same? Although the `xRadius` of the first cell matches the values of the bottom cell, the `yRadius` is off. I think the bottom cell's values are correct, because since the `ax` aspect is set to be equal, the two radii should be the same. Why is the `yRadius` of the first cell wrong here? After trying out a bunch of different values for `xlim` and `ylim` I found the pattern that the minimum of the two radii in the first cell is correct, while the other one is off. This seems to me a very strange error. Is there any way of making it return the correct values in the initial cell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your observation is pretty accurate. What happens is simply that the equal aspect is only applied once the figure is drawn. This is the case for the second cell (because the figure is shown as output of the first). However in the first cell the axes still has its original extent.

Solution: Draw the figure before trying to obtain any coordinates from it,

```
fig.canvas.draw()

# Now obtain coordinates:
yradius = (ax.transData.transform([(0,2)]) - ax.transData.transform([(0,1)]))[0,1]
print("yRadius: {}".format(yradius))
xradius = (ax.transData.transform([(2,0)]) - ax.transData.transform([(1,0)]))[0,0]
print("xRadius: {}".format(xradius))
```