# Understanding how Axes.transData depends on xlim and ylim updates

Tags: python, matplotlib, transform

I've been learning about Matplotlib transformations using the [tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html).  I found that the `Axes.transData` transformation doesn't necessarily have the information it needs.  Taking the example from that tutorial, if I remove the calls to `set_xlim` and `set_ylim`, we do not get the desired result.  One annotation is missing:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.005)
y = np.exp(-x/2.) * np.sin(2*np.pi*x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)

xdata, ydata = 5, 0
# This computing the transform now, if anything
# (figure size, dpi, axes placement, data limits, scales..)
# changes re-calling transform will get a different value.
xdisplay, ydisplay = ax.transData.transform((xdata, ydata))

bbox = dict(boxstyle="round", fc="0.8")
arrowprops = dict(
    arrowstyle="->",
    connectionstyle="angle,angleA=0,angleB=90,rad=10")

offset = 72
ax.annotate('data = (%.1f, %.1f)' % (xdata, ydata),
            (xdata, ydata), xytext=(-2*offset, offset), textcoords='offset points',
            bbox=bbox, arrowprops=arrowprops)

disp = ax.annotate('display = (%.1f, %.1f)' % (xdisplay, ydisplay),
                   (xdisplay, ydisplay), xytext=(0.5*offset, -offset),
                   xycoords='figure pixels',
                   textcoords='offset points',
                   bbox=bbox, arrowprops=arrowprops)

plt.show()
```

[image: transform example with missing annotation]

I do not want to explicitly set `xlim` and `ylim` for my use-case. I did find that if I call `ax.get_xlim()` before the call to `ax.transData.transform`, it seems to work sensibly.  Is this the best thing to use or is there a more direct way to tell the Axes to update itself so that `ax.transData` has the information it needs?  Also is there a reason the `transData` object doesn't have something built-in to make sure the limits are up-to-date before calculating a result?

Comment: I'm still looking for an **explanation** BUT, does the answer to [Why does matplotlib ax.transData.transform gives different values in different ipython cells? How to fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51447184/why-does-matplotlib-ax-transdata-transform-gives-different-values-in-different-i) answer your question.  ... `fig.canvas.draw()` seems to *populate* all the coordinate systems.

Comment: Thanks @wwii, so looking through the code base, it seems that both `draw` and `get_xlim` call `ax._unstale_viewLim()`.  I just tried calling that directly and it does reinstate the desired behaviour.  Obviously I wouldn't use the hidden method in my "real" code, but it helps to understand what's going on!

Comment: In fact `ax._unstale_viewLim()` calls `ax.autoscale_view()`, so perhaps I should just use that?

Comment: I would not call those directly - notice they start with an underscore. I'm still following the crumbs but I think to be safe I would always use Figure.draw() as it should render/scale **all** the Artists. `print(ax._stale_viewlim_x,ax._stale_viewlim_y)` before and after calls to get/set x/ylim or Figure.draw() shows changes in the state of those properties.

Comment: Maybe now that you have drilled down a little you can rephrase and ask a new/different question with a relevant title that might get the attention of someone like ImportanceOfBeingErnest.

Comment: Searching with `user:4124317 fig.canvas.draw()` might be enlightening - here is an excerpt from one answer: `...you should probably draw the canvas first before working with coordinates obtained from patches`

Comment: ... quite a few answers also with `user:4124317 ax.autoscale_view()`