# Transforming data coordinates to axes coordinates without specified x/y limits

Tags: python, matplotlib, coordinates, transform

The reason I don't want x/y limit is that I want to have multiple subplots with automatically set x/y limits.

I learned that in order to transform data -> axes coordinates, I can use `transLimits.transform()`:

```
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim(0,10)
ax.set_ylim(-1,1)
ax.transLimits.transform((0,0))
```

Which gives me [0,0.5].

But without the limits and with actual data sets, the function gives me back the original data coordinates:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Create a scatter plot
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y)
# Define the data coordinates
data_x = 3
data_y = 8
data_coords = data_x,data_y
# Convert display coordinates to axes coordinates
axes_coords = ax.transLimits.transform((data_coords))
# Retrieve the axes coordinates
axes_x, axes_y = axes_coords
# Print the axes coordinates
print(f"Axes Coordinates: ({axes_x}, {axes_y})")
# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

`axes_x`,`axes_y` should be axes coordinates, but instead it gives me data coordinates.

Is there a way to retrieve the axes coordinates of a single data point while dealing with automatically set x/y limits?

Comment: What do you need the transformed coordinates for? Maybe there is a better way to do that in the first place.

Comment: There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67334384/understanding-how-axes-transdata-depends-on-xlim-and-ylim-updates). As per comments there, and I checked with your code, a workaround would be to use `fig.canvas.draw()`

Comment: Hi mkrieger, thanks for comment. Good point.

In the boxplot using sns, I'm trying to plot text in (x,y) coordinate, with x where the boxplot is at, and y at a fixed height (let's just say at the x-axis). I was thinking to manually find the y axes coordinate where the text would hang at the x-axis, and I can get x data coordinate by ax.get_lines(), so I just needed to get that x data coordinate transformed to axes coordinate

Comment: Hi Redox, that solved it... I'm so glad I took the time to ask here before I go to sleep. Thanks guys Btw, is there a way to select answer to my question? I'm new here, so do let me know if there's any way